# Magento 2.4.4: Where do I find the HTML of category pages in Magento?

Tags: magento2, category, theme, frontend, product-review

I need to add code the code below to display Yotpo Reviews Carousel in category pages. Where is the template for category pages in Magento located? We are using a custom theme from SwissUp

I need to insert the code below.

```
<div class="yotpo yotpo-reviews-carousel" 
 data-background-color="transparent" 
 data-mode="top_rated" 
 data-type="product" 
 data-count="9" 
 data-show-bottomline="1" 
 data-autoplay-enabled="1" 
 data-autoplay-speed="3000" 
 data-show-navigation="1">&nbsp;</div>
```

The mark in the image below shows where to place the carousel.
[image]

Link to the category page. https://www.perfectmakeupmirrors.com/mirrors-shop-by-brand/jerdon.html

I want the carousel to be visible across all category pages of the site.

Comment: It would be great if you upload a screenshot and point out where you want to display the carousel.

Comment: Tu Van, added an image. Please see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml`

or `<your custom theme>/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml`

These files contain div `.products.wrapper` in category pages which you should be edited.

Open `<your custom theme>/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml` and put the code for the carousel below the **last** toolbar code:

toolbar code in magento version < 2.4.3: `<?= $block->getToolbarHtml() ?>`

toolbar code in magento version >=2.4.3: `<?= $block->getChildBlock('toolbar')->setIsBottom(true)->toHtml() ?>`

Answer (score 0):

You must add the new XML file and a new phtml file.

1. Add the catalog_category_view.xml to your custom extension or edit the catalog_category_view.xml in app/design/frontend/Your-Vendor/theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml
2. Add the pthml file to your path with your html content.

Comment: Wang, could you please specify what contents should go in catalog_category_view.xml? I need to create this as my theme already doesn't have this. Please help me here.

Comment: I added it before, but it doesn't show in the answer

Comment: <referenceBlock name="category.products">
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom-yotpo-reviews" template="your template path" after="-" />
</referenceBlock>

Comment: Thank you. Wang